# Where do I put the private ssh key?

Tags: ssh

I have set up a key pair and they work fine if I use the `-i <privateKey>` switch. Where should I put the private key such that I can just type `ssh my.remote.host` without using `-i`?

I tried putting it in `~/.ssh` on my local machine but I get prompted for a password with it there still.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~/.ssh/`: `~/.ssh/id_dsa`, `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Comment: Permissions on ~/.ssh *should* be 700.  Permissions on ~/.ssh/id_dsa and ~/.ssh/id_rsa *must* be 600 (or 400).

Comment: A bad SELinux context in enforcing mode also causes this behaviour. (denial message in audit.log in such case).

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively,  you can set up individual keys in `~/.ssh/config`. See `man ssh_config` for more infos.

Something like this:

```
    Host a.host.name
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/a.host.rsa
```

Comment: I had to change that to `IdentitiesOnly yes` and `IdentityFile` to get it to work for me on Debian.